# How do I rename the context root of Application Center in IBM MobileFirst 8.0 running on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.8?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I want to rename appcenterconsole to appcenterconsoledev, and applicationcenter to applicationcenterdev. I am running MobileFirst 8.0 on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.8. I wonder if this is as simple as rename the war file, deploy it and update the server.xml?

Tried to change the **id** and **name** field to appcenterconsoledev of application tag in server.xml and restarted the server. Server started normally and was able to login to app center console. After login to console it gives an error saying that "An unexpected error occurred (HTTP status 404)".

**Updated Application tag in Server.xml:**

```
<application id="appcenterconsoledev" name="appcenterconsoledev" location="appcenterconsole.war" type="war">
```

**Messages.log:**

```
[8/18/17 15:30:26:881 EDT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [appcenterconsoledev] [/appcenterconsoledev] [localeServlet]: Initialization successful.
[8/18/17 15:30:26:882 EDT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [appcenterconsoledev] [/appcenterconsoledev] [servicesServlet]: Initialization successful.
[8/18/17 15:30:27:478 EDT] 0000001e com.ibm.puremeap.util.PureMeapBaseUtil                       I Resource conf/jndi/default.properties not found. This is not an error. Context path is /applicationcenter
[8/18/17 15:30:27:487 EDT] 0000001e com.ibm.appcenter.servlet.ConsoleServicesServlet             I The endpoint used to invoke the ApplicationCenter administration services is http://localhost:9081/applicationcenter
```

**Console screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Adding a below JNDI service endpoint entry to the server.xml, this has been resolved and now we were able to access dev/uat appcenter consoles.

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.services.endpoint" value="*://*:*/applicationcenterdev" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the context-root attribute. Like the below example

```
<application context-root="appcenterconsoledev" type="war" id="appcenterconsole" location="appcenterconsole.war" name="appcenterconsole"/>
```

Comment: By using the context root to application tag, this hasn't resolved the issue. Please refer to the answer below for resolution.